# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) when using strcmp

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I am making an application that registers client's cars and has some filtering options. I was able to do almost all of them with ease, but the filtering by model just won't work. If someone could guide me on what I'm doing wrong it would be much appreciated.

Complete code in gitlab: https://gitlab.com/salgadoth/car-ownership-in-c/-/blob/master/carownership.c

```c
void listModel()
{
    int i, comp;
    char model[20];
    printf("\nTYPE IN DESIRED MODEL:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &model);
    printf("DESIRED MODEL: %s\n\n", model);
    
    for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(model, car[i].model) == 0)
        {
            printf("\nBRAND: %s", car[i].brand);
            printf("\nMODEL: %s", car[i].model);
            printf("\nLICENSE PLATE: %s", car[i].license_plate);
            printf("\nYEAR OF FABRICATION: %d\n", car[i].year);
            printf("---------------------------\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nERROR - NO CAR FOUND");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use `fflush(stdin)` -it's implementation-defined, at best. And you shouldn't have the `&` in `scanf("%s", &model);`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I use indentation, but as I copy/paste the code into here it lost all the indentation :/

Comment: @user3121023 car is a struct

Comment: Please edit the question to include, in text and in the question, just enough code so that we can compile it and replicate the error. Do not include any code not needed to replicate the error, and ideally replace any input code with code that just triggers the error.

Comment: @ThiagoSalgado: You can enclose code in ` characters to mark it as code. This is the only way to mark code in comments. In the actual questions and answers, you can also mark code in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize `counter`, so nothing stops your `for` loop from running into objects you didn't initialize. If `model` doesn't contain a valid string, then `strcmp` can fault.